# Rosalind translating rna into protein python

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics, rosalind

Here is my solution to the [problem](http://rosalind.info/problems/prot/) of rosalind project.

```
def prot(rna):
  for i in xrange(3, (5*len(rna))//4+1, 4):
    rna=rna[:i]+','+rna[i:]
  rnaList=rna.split(',')
  bases=['U','C','A','G']
  codons = [a+b+c for a in bases for b in bases for c in bases]
  amino_acids = 'FFLLSSSSYY**CC*WLLLLPPPPHHQQRRRRIIIMTTTTNNKKSSRRVVVVAAAADDEEGGGG'
  codon_table = dict(zip(codons, amino_acids))
  peptide=[]
  for i in range (len (rnaList)):
    if codon_table[rnaList[i]]=='*':
      break
    peptide+=[codon_table[rnaList[i]]]
  output=''
  for i in peptide:
    output+=str(i)
  return output
```

If I run `prot('AUGGCCAUGGCGCCCAGAACUGAGAUCAAUAGUACCCGUAUUAACGGGUGA')`, I get the correct output `'MAMAPRTEINSTRING'`. However if the sequence of rna (the input string) is hundreds of nucleotides (characters) long I got an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<stdin>", line 11, in prot
 KeyError: 'CUGGAAACGCAGCCGACAUUCGCUGAAGUGUAG'
```

Can you point me where I went wrong?

Comment: Where is the rest of the traceback?

Comment: Actually it only says that. I'm starting to think that the problem is on the `break`. But from the document, it seems that I applied it correctly.

Comment: No, the problem is in your splitting the `rna` into three-character chunks

Comment: Consider reading the forum of the problem there are more hints there about how to solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have a `KeyError`, the problem must be in one of your attempts to access `codon_table[rnaList[i]]`.  You are assuming each item in `rnalist` is three characters, but evidently, at some point, that stops being `True` and one of the items is `'CUGGAAACGCAGCCGACAUUCGCUGAAGUGUAG'`.

This happens because when you reassign `rna = rna[:i]+','+rna[i:]` you *change the length of `rna`*, such that your indices `i` no longer reach the end of the list. This means that for any `rna` where `len(rna) > 60`, the last item in the list will not have length 3. If there is a stop codon before you reach the item it isn't a problem, but if you reach it you get the `KeyError`.

I suggest you rewrite the start of your function, e.g. using the `grouper` [recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def prot(rna):
    rnaList = ["".join(t) for t in grouper(rna, 3)]
    ...
```

Note also that you can use

```
peptide.append(codon_table[rnaList[i]])
```

and

```
return "".join(peptide)
```

to simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, but note that you could solve this very succinctly using [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page):

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC

def rna2prot(rna):
    rna = Seq(rna, IUPAC.unambiguous_rna)
    return str(rna.translate(to_stop=True))
```

For example:

```
>>> print rna2prot('AUGGCCAUGGCGCCCAGAACUGAGAUCAAUAGUACCCGUAUUAACGGGUGA')
MAMAPRTEINSTRING
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for breaking the rna into 3-char blocks is a bit nasty; you spend a lot of time breaking and rebuilding strings to no real purpose.

Building the codon_table only needs to be done once, not every time your function is run.

Here is a simplified version:

```
from itertools import product, takewhile

bases = "UCAG"
codons = ("".join(trio) for trio in product(bases, repeat=3))
amino_acids = 'FFLLSSSSYY**CC*WLLLLPPPPHHQQRRRRIIIMTTTTNNKKSSRRVVVVAAAADDEEGGGG'
codon_table = dict(zip(codons, amino_acids))

def prot(rna):
    rna_codons = [rna[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(rna) - 2, 3)]
    aminos = takewhile(
        lambda amino: amino != "*",
        (codon_table[codon] for codon in rna_codons)
    )
    return "".join(aminos)
```

Comment: Given that you're using `itertools` for two other things, I'm surprised you build a list instead of using `grouper`.

Comment: Well, (a) you already demonstrated that very nicely ;-)  (b) it's simple enough to just do it as a list comprehension, and (c) `fillvalue` seems like a bad idea here (I tweaked the termination value such that there will be no partial blocks, any leftover will just be truncated)